# Update multiple row with result of subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I've a swap table with this structure (showing one example row):

```
title       | author_firstname | author_lastname | genre
------------+------------------+-----------------+-----------
the promise | robert           | crails          | thriller
```

In another table `genre` I have all book genres. I want to insert the id of corresponding genre in a third table `book`. The book title was inserted with this query:

```
INSERT INTO book(title) SELECT title FROM swap_book;
```

The structure of book table is:

```
id | title | genre_id
```

I need to do this using Kettle and for every row in swap table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a `genre` table like:

```
CREATE TABLE genre(genre_id serial PRIMARY KEY, genre text UNIQUE NOT NULL);
```

You *can* do an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE book b
SET    genre_id = g.genre_id
FROM   swap_book s
JOIN   genre g ON g.genre = s.genre
WHERE  b.title = s.title;
```

This requires `title` to be unique in both tables.

It's obviously better to do it all in a single `INSERT` instead:

```
INSERT INTO book (title, genre_id)
SELECT s.title, g.genre_id
FROM   swap_book s
LEFT   JOIN genre g ON g.genre = s.genre;
```

I use `LEFT JOIN` to preserve the row if no matching genre is found. You get NULL for `genre_id` in this case. Same result as after the `UPDATE` above.
Depending on your secret requirements, there may be other options ...

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO book(title, genre_id) 
select title, genre.id 
from swap_book 
  inner join swap_book.genre=genre.genrename
```

I am assuming the name of genre in genre table is genrename.

Comment: So do you want to udpate the existing swap_book table instead of creating a new book table that you have in your question?